# Does anyone know where JFactory::getApplication()->getParams() is declared?

Tags: development, joomla-api, joomla-3.3.x

I'm working on my MVSC implementation. I'm planning on adding a function called `getParams()` to my base view, so that I don't have to keep merging item, menu, and component params before rendering the view.

Up until know I've been using `JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();` which gets the active menu params.

I want to look at the implementation and maybe avoid having to use the application if there was already a dedicated class, but I can't find any mention of `getParams()` in any of the JApplication classes (J3.3.0).

I can only assume that it is late static binding, but does anyone know where this method is attached to the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the file *libraries/cms/application/site.php*. The administrator (back end) file has no such function specified.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that we are actually using two different subclasses of JApplicationCms!